# Any way to prevent Safari edge swipe (on iPhone, for example)?

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

I've been researching how to prevent Safari's feature of swiping at the edge of the screen to navigate to previous/next pages in browser history.  I have an application that uses Hammer.js to pan an image, and on mobile the image takes up the whole screen.  So if the user happens to start panning at the left edge of the image, for example, it forgoes that by ignoring my little javascript app and instead going to the previous page.  I haven't found anything saying it is actually possible to prevent this edge swipe feature...though I did find this: https://gist.github.com/mountainstorm/9430618.  However, all it seemed to accomplish for me was breaking mouse scroll functionality.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: This is possible since iOS 13.4: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62308410/1774081

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it can be done since it is an OS level feature. As long as the swipes initiate inside the web page, there should not be any issue. If you have sufficient margin from the edge, then it should not be a problem.